# Append new rows having unique key value in table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `id_test1` with this sample data :

```
P_Key   Name    phone   address     zip
1   a   123 NCR 1002
2   b   456 LKO 12045
3   c   789 BLR 3652
4   d   987 DLI 4528
5   e   654 NCR 7854
```

I have a another table `id_test2` with this data:

```
P_Key   Name    phone   address     zip
1   x   985 NCR 1002
2   y   562 LKO 12045
3   z   365 BLR 3652
4   q   362 DLI 4528
5   w   124 NCR 7854
```

I want to merge the tables into 1 new table called `id_test`. But the `p_key` column should be unique. I want to merge these two table's data into single one as below:

```
P_Key   Name    phone   address     zip
1   a   123 NCR 1002
2   b   456 LKO 12045
3   c   789 BLR 3652
4   d   987 DLI 4528
5   e   654 NCR 7854
6   x   985 NCR 1002
7   y   562 LKO 12045
8   z   365 BLR 3652
9   q   362 DLI 4528
10  w   124 NCR 7854
```

I had worked in Oracle database and I am new to SQL Server 2008. Please provide your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, there is a neat little tool called if exists.

It isn't perfect, but for the novice programmer, it works pretty good.

Since I don't understand your structure, lets pretend you had a simple table of ID and Name.  ID must be unique.

```
You want to add
ID=1, Name=A
ID=2, Name=B
ID=1, Name=C

You want it to end up with:
ID=1, Name=A:C
ID=2, Name=B
```

Your SQL looks something like:

```
@ID = <id of thing you are inserting>
@NAME = <name of thing you are inserting>

if exists (select * from table where ID = @ID)
BEGIN
   UPDATE table set NAME = NAME + ',' + @NAME where ID = @ID
END
else
BEGIN
   INSERT values (@ID, @NAME) into table
END
```

My SQL syntax may need some slight editing, but you should get the idea.  For instance, I doubt I have the proper syntax for concatenating varchars.

Comment: No..i have two tables a_test having data   ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 c    another tbale b_test having data ID Name
1 d
2 e
3 f  i want to merge both table in new table c_test having data from both but it has unique id like below:   ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f

Comment: i want to do this in a single statment..i have tried with union but facing isue with ID column...i am not able to pass ID column value correctly.Please assist.

Comment: please assist .Please let me know if any other information required on this.@owen Ivory

Answer (score 0):

if you use an identity column for P_Key in new table, then following query will do the task

```
INSERT INTO id_test
(
    Name,phone,address,zip
)
SELECT Name,phone,address,zip FROM id_test1 ORDER BY P_Key

INSERT INTO id_test
(
    Name,phone,address,zip
)
SELECT Name,phone,address,zip FROM id_test2 ORDER BY P_Key
```

if you are not using identity column you can use folowing query using row_number

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY P_Key ORDER BY P_Key,Name),T.Name,T.phone,T.address,T.zip
FROM
(
    SELECT P_Key,Name,phone,address,zip FROM id_test1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P_Key,Name,phone,address,zip FROM id_test2 
)T
```